# Determining whether series converges or diverges

Tags: sequences-and-series

So say I have the series  $\sum$$a_n$  where $a_n$:=$\frac{(-1)^{n-1}n}
{n+1}$

Taking |$a_n$|=$\frac{n}{n+1}$ we notice its limit is equal to 1 so series doesn't converge absolutely.
But it may still converge absolutely right? How could I determine if it does or not?

Also if $\sum$$a_n$ where $a_n$:=$\frac{n^2+n(-1)^n}{(n^6+1)^\frac{1}{2}}$
any tips on showing it diverges?

I started off by saying $a_n \leq \frac{n^2+n}{(n^6+1)^\frac{1}{2}}<\frac{n^2+n}{n^3}$ which doesnt seem to help. Original question was to determine whether it converges or diverges, so thats why I started like that not knowing it diverges at start.

Comment: Neither absolutely nor conditionally. Conditional convergence still implies $a_n\to 0$.

Comment: You cannot show that, because the series diverges by noting $a_n \not\to 0$.

Comment: so all I should say is limit $\sum$$a_n$= 1 or -1 which is different than zero right?

Answer (score 1):

The given series does not converge at all, let alone converge absolutely, because if $\sum a_n < \infty$(conditional convergence), then $a_n \to 0$ must happen, but this is not the case here, because $a_n$ is a divergent sequence : it has two branches converging to $1$ and $-1$(which are different from $0$).

As for the second question, note that $a_n \to 0$ is true in this case. However, we know that $\sum \frac 1n$ diverges, and somewhere we see a $\frac 1n$ above, because the dominating term(term with highest power of $n$) on the numerator is $n^2$, and on the denominator is $(n^6)^\frac 12 = n^3$, so $a_n$ behaves "like" $\frac 1n$ for large values of $n$.

More precisely, you want to use the comparison theorem for series. Show that there is a constant $C$ that $a_n \geq C\frac 1n$ for and all $n > N$(for some $N$). One you do this, the comparison theorem gives you the result.

Comment: So for the second part could I say for large n.... ? and thanks for your answer

Comment: Yes. See, the comparison theorem says : if  there are series $c_n$ and $d_n$ with $\sum d_n = \infty$(diverges) and $c_n > d_n$ for all $n$, then $\sum c_n = \infty$. What I am saying, is a strengthening : if $\sum d_n = \infty$, and there exist $N,C  > 0$ such that $n > N$ implies $c_n > Cd_n$, then too $\sum c_n = \infty$. I am asking you to find $C,N$ so that you can use this stronger version above.